# Corrplot: highlight specific correlation?

Tags: r, r-corrplot

Does anybody know a way to highlight a specific correlation in a corrplot, for example by additionally plotting the correlation value. 
I have a 6x6 correlation matrix and use the method = "color" and want to highlight one value with the method "number". (it does not necessarily need to be the method "number", any way to highlight it is good)

Thanks and best
Jakob

Comment: please revise your question according the guidelines.

Comment: There appears to be no obvious way of doing it, but one possibility is to make your correlation of interest `NA` in the source matrix and then give use the `na.label.col` argument to give it the colour you want.